# Panda dataframe column cut - add more bins more frequently around the mean

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am categorizing quantitative variable (e.g. price) and I would like to categorize it in the manner that the bins would be much more frequent around the mean and less when away from the mean.

I have seen that there are possibilities to cut() in linear manner and thanks to numpy.logspace in logarithmic manner, but binning around the mean seems to be void and my ideas so far haven't worked and seem to be inefficient.

Comment: No clue how cut works, but can you perhaps translate your whole dataset around 0 such that the linear option would work?

Comment: You mean standardizing or scaling? Doesn't it still give me the same result like before? Having very popular categories because of the normal distribution.

Comment: I tried executing what I meant in the answer below. Not sure if this is what you wanted, but it might work for your purposes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make bins that increase in size linearly:

```
import numpy as np

def make_progressive_bins(min_x, max_x, mean_x, num_bins=10):
    x_rel_lim = max(mean_x - min_x, mean_x - max_x)
    num_bins_half = num_bins // 2
    bins_right = np.arange(0, num_bins_half + 1)
    if num_bins % 2 == 1:
        bins_right = bins_right + 0.5
    bins_right = np.cumsum(bins_right)
    bins = np.concatenate([-bins_right[bins_right > 0][::-1], bins_right])
    bins = bins * (float(x_rel_lim) / bins[-1]) + mean_x
    return bins
```

And then you can use it like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = make_progressive_bins(-20, 50, 10, 15)
plt.bar(bins - 0.1, np.ones_like(bins), 0.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made a script that might do what you want to achieve, but I'm not sure how to convert the resulted cut object into a histogram to see if it does what i want it to do, so please check and tell me if it works :).

```
# Make normally distributed price with mean 50.
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(50, size=1000), columns=['price'])
df.hist(bins=30)

num_bins = 100

# I used a square function to distribute the bins more around 0 and 
# less at the outskirts of the range.
shape_func = lambda x: x**2

bin_loc = [shape_func(i) for i in range(num_bins//2)]
mirrored_bin_loc = [-x for x in bin_loc[::-1]]
bin_loc = mirrored_bin_loc + bin_loc[1:]

# Rescale and translate bins
data_mean = df.price.mean()
data_range = df.price.max() - df.price.min()
final_bin_loc = [(x + data_mean) / (data_range * num_bins) for x in bin_loc]

# display(final_bin_loc)
binned = pd.cut(df.price, bin_loc)
```

Comment: It seems that it is doing the same thing, but I am now eliminating the negative values (values, which go other side of the df.column.min() and put the center place around the mean rather than around the 0.